# overriding/extending price-options.js does not work

Tags: magento2, price, javascript

I need to override/extend the file `price-options.js`.
But it does not work, I always get the error

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor

on this line

```
 $.widget('myCompany.mypriceoptions', $.mage.priceOptions, {
```

Here are my files:

**myCompany\myModule\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            priceOptions: 'myCompany_myModule/js/price-options',

        }
    }
};
```

**myCompany\myModule\view\frontend\web\js\price-options.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'priceUtils',
    'priceBox',
    'priceOptions'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, utils) {
    'use strict';
    var globalOptions = {
        qtyFieldSelector: 'input.qty',
    };
    $.widget('myCompany.mypriceoptions', $.mage.priceOptions, {
        options: globalOptions,

        _onOptionChanged: function onOptionChanged(event) {
            console.log('TEST!');
            var changes,
                option = $(event.target),
                handler = this.options.optionHandlers[option.data('role')];
            option.data('optionContainer', option.closest(this.options.controlContainer));

            if (handler && handler instanceof Function) {
                changes = handler(option, this.options.optionConfig, this);
            } else {
                changes = defaultGetOptionValue(option, this.options.optionConfig);
            }
            $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).trigger('updatePrice', changes);
        },


    });

    return $.myCompany.mypriceoptions;


});
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to use mixins:

**myCompany\myModule\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {

    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-options': {
                'myCompany_myModule/js/price-options': true
            }
        }
    }

};
```

**myCompany\myModule\view\frontend\web\js\price-options.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'priceUtils',
    'priceBox',
    'priceOptions'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, utils) {
    'use strict';
    return function (priceOptions) {

        return $.widget('mage.priceOptions', priceOptions, {

            _onOptionChanged: function onOptionChanged(event) {
                console.log('TEST!');
                var changes,
                    option = $(event.target),
                    handler = this.options.optionHandlers[option.data('role')];
                option.data('optionContainer', option.closest(this.options.controlContainer));

                if (handler && handler instanceof Function) {
                    changes = handler(option, this.options.optionConfig, this);
                } else {
                    changes = defaultGetOptionValue(option, this.options.optionConfig);
                }
                $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).trigger('updatePrice', changes);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

The Result is that the .js file appears in the browser, but still the magento function is used instead of the costume one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixins functionality may help us to solve our issue:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html
- http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/

In your `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            priceOptions: {
                'Namespace_Modulename/js/price-options': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Read more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7322

Comment: I tried the exact same example from github. It does not work, the js does show up in the browser, but the custom reloadPrice function doesn´t get fired.

Comment: You should update the question with what you tried. I will test on my local machine.

Comment: I did update the question

Comment: @TrytoFly remember static files need to be cleared

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Can I call this js file in cms page only in my custom module?

Comment: Magento2.3 Overriding `'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'` via mixin works in only Chrome browser. Have an any idea?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh have you get any solution?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Yes.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh what is the issue? why it happened? Do you get proper reason?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Yes

Comment: @DhadukMitesh please tell me whta is the reason and how can solve?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22338 Please see in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99994/discussion-between-rutvee-sojitra-and-dhaduk-mitesh).

Comment: @DhadukMitesh can you check discussion window

Answer (score 5):

Can confirm - the mixin approach worked for me.

In `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-options': {
                'Namespace_Modulename/js/price-options-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and my mixin file `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/price-options-mixin.js`

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.priceOptions', widget, {

            _onOptionChanged: function () {
                alert("This was called instead of the parent _onOptionChanged function");
            }

        });
        return $.mage.priceOptions;
    }
});
```

Then run this from the CLI:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```